# How can I encapsulate Java into a DLL and then call the DLL from Excel VBA?

Tags: java, vba, dll, encapsulation

I have a Java program and I need to acess it from Excel VBA. 
The way I want to do it is encapsulating the java to a DLL so then I can call it from VBA.

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea.  Java byte code and .Net code are inherently incompatible.  Any option you use to do this is going to be bloated, slow, complicated, and likely un-reliable from one user to the next.  It would be better to have the Java app be a service your app could call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one of my project, I have use IKVM : http://sourceforge.net/projects/ikvm/

> IKVM.NET is a JVM for the Microsoft .NET Framework and Mono. It can
>   both dynamically run Java classes and can be used to convert Java jars
>   into .NET assemblies. It also includes a port of the OpenJDK class
>   libraries to .NET.

And this thread to help you to use it with Excel VBA : http://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/mailman/message/32106884/
Perhaps, this can help you.

Comment: He said he is using VBA which I do not think is a .Net so I am not sure if that will work, but I could be wrong.